Langchain library to calculate throughput
I want to calculate input and output throughput for a model. i am using Lang chain framework. so want to know does Lang chain provide any library which will help me to calculate the prompt eval time, total time, model load time etc. Can i get parameters like these using any Lang chain library ??
if anyone knows please help me this and provide some resource as well.
i tried out with Ollama.chat and i was able to get this but want something from Lang chain library.
so this is what i got from ollama.chat -
{
  'model': 'zephyr:latest',
  'created_at': '2024-05-13T16:41:29.1417772Z',
  'message': {
    'role': 'assistant',
    'content': ''
  },
  'done': True,
  'total_duration': 24133554800,
  'load_duration': 506800,
  'prompt_eval_count': 15,
  'prompt_eval_duration': 1829290000,
  'eval_count': 112,
  'eval_duration': 22295743000
}

